# Automatically Publish Composite Locator Service with Rebuilt Address Locators

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, address

I'm using a composite address locator with ArcGIS Server 10.3.  It is based on 6 other address locators.

I'm trying to find a quick way to rebuild all of the address locators and publish the composite locator service to ArcGIS Server.

Is this possible through the command line or with Python?